# CustomUITableViewCell not showing subviews on all Simulators

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have tableView with Custom cells. The custom cells have two buttons. The problem I am having is that the buttons in the cell don't show on all simulators, Actually they only show on iphone5 and ipad2 simulators but not the others. Any one has a clue?

Attached screenshots(iphone5 & iphone5S) and customCell code.

[image]
[image]

```
@interface AWSCameraProfileTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *videoButton;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *uploadToCloudButton;
@end


@implementation AWSCameraProfileTableViewCell
@synthesize videoButton,uploadToCloudButton;


- (void)awakeFromNib {
[super awakeFromNib];
// Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}


//  This is the one that is typically called
//  to set up our cell from the storyboard.
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

if (self)
{
    // Initialization code
    self.cellID = 1;//cInvalidCellID;

    // Install the custom background
    self.tableViewCellBackgroundView = [TableViewCellBackgroundView newTableViewCellBackgroundViewWithFrame:self.frame
                                                                                            backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1
                                                                                                                              alpha:0.7]];
    [self addSubview:self.tableViewCellBackgroundView];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:self.tableViewCellBackgroundView];


    NSLog(@"origin(%f,%f) Size(%f,%f)",self.contentView.bounds.origin.x,self.contentView.bounds.origin.y, self.contentView.bounds.size.height,self.contentView.bounds.size.width);

    videoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 //   [videoButton addTarget:self
  //             action:@selector(videoButtonClicked:)
  //   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [videoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    videoButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.contentView.bounds.size.width- 40, 10.0, 36.0, 36.0);
    [self.contentView addSubview:videoButton];

    uploadToCloudButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 //   [uploadToCloudButton addTarget:self
 //                   action:@selector(cloudButtonClicked:)
 //         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [uploadToCloudButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudUpload.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    uploadToCloudButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.contentView.bounds.size.width- 40, 10.0, 36.0, 36.0);
    [self.contentView addSubview:uploadToCloudButton];


}

return self;
}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (self)
{
    // Initialization code
    self.cellID = -1; //cInvalidCellID;

    // Install the custom background
    self.tableViewCellBackgroundView = [TableViewCellBackgroundView newTableViewCellBackgroundViewWithFrame:self.frame
                                                                                            backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1
                                                                                                                              alpha:0.7]];
    [self addSubview:self.tableViewCellBackgroundView];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:self.tableViewCellBackgroundView];

    [self addSubview:self.videoButton];
    [self addSubview:self.uploadToCloudButton];
}

return self;
}


- (void) setCellID:(int)cellID
{
 _cellID = cellID;
 self.imageView.image = [UIImage   imageNamed:@"DefaultCameraPreview100x100"],false;//[[CellManager shared] previewImageForCellID:cellID];
 }


 - (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

float   imageDiameter = self.frame.size.height * 100. / 120.;
self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageDiameter, imageDiameter);

float inset = (self.frame.size.height - imageDiameter) / 2.0;

// Make iOS 7 look like iOS 6
// by performing explicit placement of image and label.
// This doesn't affect iOS 6.
CGRect  imageViewFrame = self.imageView.frame;
imageViewFrame.origin.x = inset;
self.imageView.frame = imageViewFrame;

CGRect  textLabelFrame = self.textLabel.frame;
textLabelFrame.origin.x = inset + imageDiameter + inset;
textLabelFrame.size.width = self.contentView.frame.size.width -   self.frame.size.height;
self.textLabel.frame = textLabelFrame;

// Make sure the background view frame matches the cell view frame.
CGRect  tableViewCellBackgroundViewFrame = self.tableViewCellBackgroundView.frame;
tableViewCellBackgroundViewFrame.size = self.frame.size;
self.tableViewCellBackgroundView.frame = tableViewCellBackgroundViewFrame;

videoButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width-40, 10.0, 36.0, 36.0);
uploadToCloudButton.frame =  CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width-40, 10.0, 36.0, 36.0);

 }


 @end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are placing these subviews using absolute values for `self.contentView.bounds.size`. You can't do that, because at the time this code runs, the cell has not yet been given its real size. Thus, you are ending up with the buttons off the screen.

Your best choice would be to position the subviews using autolayout. That way, you can pin them to the right edge of the cell, no matter what its size turns out to be.

Comment: Should I be doing this from storyboard? My goal is exactly what you mentioned, to pin them to the right edge.

Comment: You could do it through both storyboards or code - try reading the [apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html) on how to create programmatic constraints.

Comment: Thanks - it's what I was looking for.